# While committing in SVN i can't get the latest version : Commit failed

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I got this error after clicking into SVN Commit :

```
Error: Commit failed (details follow):  

Error: File or directory 'alerts\ALT_602_NewAlert.java' is out of date; try updating
```

[image]

PS: Updated Question ==> After Update :

Also I'm getting this 'text status' after making an update and a new commit :

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the original message suggested, in SVN is a newer version of the file(s) you try to check in, so you have to `svn update` first.

Regarding the errors you got on your second try, when doing `svn update` you should have read the output of the command. It told you that there were conflicts. You have to resolve those conflicts first before you are able to commit. Here you can read more about resolving conflicts in SVN: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve

Comment: @bahrep why did you change my link? 1.7 is the latest officially released version according to the homepage

Comment: I'd suggest using SVNBook 1.8 links because 1.8 version of the book is mostly ready and it covers up-to-date SVN 1.8 features.